# Harry Potter fanfic: Snape takes care of a baby Harry

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, severus-snape, fan-fiction

Most likely read on FF.net. I can't remember if it was a de-ageing accident or if it was a "Snape rescues/adopts Harry as a baby".

The most prominent portion of the story that I can only remember standing out was the detail of Snape's living quarters which had now been transformed to accommodate the baby Potter. Probably from Dumbledore's meddling, there was now a giant, lumpy, disgustingly soft blanket (play-mat) in the middle/center of his room/living room/floor. Just one look at it was repulsive to him (Snape), and it looked so soft it looked as if it would make him sink into the floor if he even dared to step foot on it.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be [If Things Were Different by angelofjoy?](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/5299831/1/If-Things-Were-Different)

> AU: Lily takes life and death in her own hands and goes to the one
>   person she had always trusted, Severus Snape. Now, after her death, he
>   is left to keep his promise and to raise a child on his own. NOTE:
>   nothing in this story is cannon [sic].

I haven't read the whole thing, but it is 166 chapters and ongoing.

Comment: @Stormblessed "[sic]" is used alongside the error *instead* of fixing it.

Comment: @Laurel OK, that always confused me

Answer (score 1):

Could it be ["My Little Runaway"](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/12698404/1/My-Little-Runaway) by [BlueRowley](https://www.fanfiction.net/u/6851161/BlueRowley) on FanFiction.net?

> After Harry Potter runs away from his relatives' home for the sixth time, Albus decides something drastic must happen. Instead of sending a friendly witch from family services like he had done before, he sends Severus Snape in hopes of scaring the boy into staying put. But when a storm interferes with plans, Severus realizes why Harry runs away and a change of plans ensues.

Snape moves Harry to Hogwarts where he hides him from Dumbledore. I can remember parts where he buys Harry some things such as the blanket.

Comment: At first glance, this does not seem to involve a baby Harry.

Comment: that is correct, it is more a 5-6 year old Harry who has been traumatised till the point that he gets constant emotional breakdowns.